# FGLRX doesn't show in Additional Drivers

Tags: 11.04, drivers, dell, fglrx

I have Dell Studio 15 with ATI mobility HD 4500 Series graphics card.

In Ubuntu 10.10 I used the FLGRX driver which I installed from the Additional Drivers program, I need this because the open source driver runs my computer dangerously hot.

In 11.04 FGLRX is not available in the Additional Drivers program.

Why is FGLRX not showing in Additional Drivers and how do I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because they are not installed? I have these drivers in Additional Driver application.

You can just install `fglrx` package using some package manager or just type in console:

```
sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

If you want use the newest version of these driver you have to also add PPA repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
```

Comment: I installed fglrx but it's still not showing in additional drivers.

Comment: @trampster It is hard to say for me why you don't see them. But maybe these drivers are installed and worked. You check your Xorg.0.log file: `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep fglrx`

Comment: If your drivers are not loaded you have to change xorg.conf. you can use such command `sudo aticonfig --initial` to create  a new `xorg.conf` version.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get remove fglrx
```

then for newest ati driver:

```
wget http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run
```

***If you have a 64 bit system, then install this before anything:***

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

Once dowloaded right-click the .run file and set it to run as executable.

then.

```
cd /path_of_the_file
```

***This is for 32 bit only:***

```
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run
```

***This is for 64 bit only:***

```
sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-11-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/natty

sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Once it's done.

```
  sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

that's all you have to do.

Alternatively you can add this ppa.

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install fglrx
```

Answer (score -1):

I was in exactly the same situation, having a radeon hd 3450 card, in 12.04. After a normal x.org update (possibly from the backports repository?), suddenly the fglrx driver appeared in jockey, and I was able to install it successfully.

Comment: -1. This is a comment and doesn't answer the original question. Please delete or edit with an actionable response to answer the question